# Integrating Javascript to aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Good Day. I am trying to integrate this javascript code to my aspx page.
I found the code below when I was looking for a tristate checkbox for asp.net webforms.

Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="ts(this)"  runat="server"/>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ts(cb) {
            if (cb.readOnly)
                cb.checked = cb.readOnly = false;
            else if (!cb.checked)
                cb.readOnly = cb.indeterminate = true;
        }
    </script>
```

Basically what I want to happen is when checkbox was click it will execute a certain datasource specified for it and display it in the gridview.

Example:

> DataSource1 : Select * from Students
>
> DataSource2 : Select * from Students Where Gender = 'Male'
>
> DataSource3 : Select * from Students Where Gender = 'Female'

Since the checkbox was customized. I want it to execute a certain datasource depending on what state it is , check/uncheck/null(indeterminate). My problem is , I am new to JS and no prior experience. I don't know how to execute the datasource through the JS code above or access it in code behind.

Comment: You can use `Ajax` on `cb.click` function.

Comment: Is there a way I can do it without using ajax?

Comment: Actually you can run your database queries on server side...>So with javascript it can only be done with ajax

Answer (score 0):

**Suggestion:**

Replace your aspx code

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclick="ts(this)" runat="server"/>
```

With this

```
<input type="checkbox" id="cb1" onclientclick="ts(this); return false;" runat="server"/>
```